# Script para Tabelas Indesign (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, tabela-html, css

Criei um script para o Indesign usando o JavaScript, contudo não estou sabendo criar um ultimo comando para concluir ele:

```
myTable ();


function myTable(){
      app.selection[0].tables.everyItem().appliedTableStyle = "Tabela";

        var    
            mCols = app.activeDocument.textFrames[0].tables[0].columns[-1],
            mTarget = mCols.cells.everyItem().texts.everyItem().getElements(),
            len = mTarget.length;  
        while (len-->0)
            mTarget[len].tabStops.add({  
              alignment: TabStopAlignment.CHARACTER_ALIGN,
              alignmentCharacter: ",",
              position: mCols.width -10
            }); 
        alert("Script myTable");
}
```

Esse meu script me entrega esse resultando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas preciso que os "R$" também fiquem alinhados alguém poderia me auxiliar.

Comment: Coloca aqui o HTML e não uma imagem pf.

Comment: inclua o código e não uma figura do mesmo na sua pergunta

Comment: O "último comando" que você está falando, é o alinhamento de "R$" com o "Item _numero_" ?